# Content Type fields with multiple words display as multiple facets

Tags: drupal-7, filtering, faceted-search, facet

I implemented filtering through facets and facing a very strange problem.

I have been trying a content type with a field for Region. Region contains options like North America, Latin America, Asia, etc. In my facets, it ends up looking like this (screenshot attached as well):

REGION:
america
asia
north
latin

[image: Facets Picture]

What I am hoping is that it shows me the way I entered it in the system.

Why is it breaking at the spaces and turning "North America" into "North" and "America"?

The field type is "Text" though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I was using Search API for indexing, and within that type of field to index was set to Fulltext. I changed it to String and it got fixed.

Thanks.